# How do I place the second component in between the divs of another component and view in the result in app.component.html

Tags: angular

I want to display divs in order as follows:
This is modal from second component
This is message 1
This is message 2
This is message 3
message 1 and 3 are in the first component while modal and message 2 are in a separate second component.

This is the content of the first component:

```
<!-- Place modal here from second.component -->
<div>This is message 1</div>    
<!-- Place message 2 here from second.component -->    
<div>This is message 3</div>
```

This is the content of the second component:

```
<div>This is modal from second component</div>
<!-- Place message 1 here from first.component -->
<div>This is message 2</div>
<!-- Place message 2 here from first.component -->
```

This is what I have done;

```
<app-first-component></app-first-component>
<app-second-component></app-second-component>
```

This is my stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvrodx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow my steps

`app.component.html` replace code like

```
<app-first-component>
  <app-second-component></app-second-component> // This will draw inside of ng-content tag of aap-first-component.html
</app-first-component>
```

and `app-first-component.html` code replace like

```
<p>header component</p>
<ng-content></ng-content> // you can adjust this tag at start, end or center as you want.
<p>sidebar compnent</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Zia, I am sorry I was not very specific in my first question. I updated my question. Hoping for an updated answer from you too.

Comment: Its ok to use the second component in the first component. There are four overlapping divs. Each component after another

Comment: My real life scenario is that the <app-first-component> is navigation menu with side nav. <div>message 1 is the top menu and <div>message 3 is the side bar navigation. The <div>message 2  in the second component is the is the actual page content. Your first code works perfectly if there is no modal pop-ups. But second page component has modals. The modal should be on top of <app-first-component> so it will display properly. Please see my updated stackblitz